# Redirect in facebook iframe app on multiple pages

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, iframe, redirect

small problem with my iframe facebook app. I want to use the app on many fb pages (so I won't know the exact urls of the FB pages) in a tab. But there is a problem with the redirect after the app asks for the permissions. Instead of the fb page, it redirects user to my canvas URL, and that is wrong! How to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Dont use the redirect method for fan pages aka Tabs ,just call the following method in java script to get permission.

```
 function getPermission(){

     FB.ui({

       'method': 'permissions.request',

       'perms': 'publish_stream,email,user_photos',



      },

  function(response) {

    if (response.perms != null) {

 // user is already connected
token=response.session.access_token;
uid=response.session.uid;


     }

     else if(response.status=="connected")
     {
token=response.session.access_token;
uid=response.session.uid;

// new user is now connected

     }




            else

            {

// user has not given a permission hence not connected.

                }

 });

return false;

}
```

Comment: have you tested this code with the latest changes to the javascript SDK? shouldn't it be "scope" instead of "perms" and "authResponse" instead of "session"? - Oh, and what is the advantage over FB.login?

Comment: If you are using Oauth 2.0 then yes it should be,if not this should work.

Comment: "As of December 13th, 2011, the JavaScript SDK now only supports OAuth 2.0 for authentication. The ability to enable OAuth 2.0 in the JS SDK was first introduced in July. All apps were given until October 1, 2011 to test and migrate. With this change, please ensure that you replaced response.session with response.authResponse. To ask for permissions, you must use scope instead of perms. Read more about the specific changes here." - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

Comment: So, still using anything that's referring to pre-OAuth2.0 is highly risky.

Answer (score 0):

If you only ask once for login/permissions (this won't handle getting permissions when needed), something like this should work:

```
function withLogin(callback) {
  var ifLogin = function(response, true_cb, else_cb) {
    if(response.authResponse)
      true_cb(null, response);
    else
      else_cb(true, null);
  };

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    ifLogin(response, callback, function(err, response) {
      FB.login(
        function(response) {
          ifLogin(response, callback, callback);
        },
        { scope: "email,user_photos" }
      );
    });
  });
}

...
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  ...
  withLogin(function(err, response) {
    if(err)
      alert("This only works if you log in!");
    else
      alert("UserId: " + response.authResponse.userID);
  });
};
```